# How can I show my flex child first with order: 1 without setting order: 2, etc. on the remaining children?

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been looking into the Flexbox property `order: 1` to arrange my div to be first when its class is set to `.default-address`. My problem is there are any number of `.address` divs following this, so I can't use `order: 2`, `order: 3`, etc.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
.default-address {
    order: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="default-address">123 Sesame Street</div>
    <div class="address">5th Avenue</div>
    <div class="address">1600 Pennsylvania Avenue</div>
    <div class="address">221 B Baker St.</div>
</div>
```

Is there a way I can define the first order without the others being defined?

Comment: Share your code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The initial value of `order` is zero for all flex items. Flex items with the same `order` value are laid out according to how they appear in the source. So to place a flex item first, you can simply give it `order: -1` instead of `order: 1`, and you do not have to worry about how many other items there are:

```css
.default-address {
  order: -1;
}
```